# add border to button when pressed

Tags: android, button, border

i want to add a border to my imagebutton when i press it.

Now i have this code:

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ficha"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textElementos"
            android:layout_marginStart="20px"
            android:background="@drawable/bordebotonespaleta"
            android:onClick="pintarFicha"
            android:src="@drawable/fichapaleta" />
```

And this is my drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/botonpressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

This is buttonpressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#e6ff0000" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="35dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="#1DE9B6" />
</shape>
```

This code does not work for me. I dont know why.

I use this like reference [How to change the color of the color button when pressed in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117086/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-color-button-when-pressed-in-android) but as i say, this not work for me.

Comment: you can change the border color, when the button is click programmatically. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23175014/4056108)

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? does it switch the state?

Comment: i want to say that the border when i press the button does not appear, but the state change to isPressed = true

Comment: try to remove the `size` element on your drawable, because it is background, its size should be dynamic, depending on the content.